# Template class strange behaviour VS2013

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constructor, visual-studio-2013

I have a template class:

```
template <class T>
class Wrapper {
public:
    Wrapper() {};

    Wrapper(const T& object) : mObject(object){ };

    template <class F, class... Args >
    typename void operation(const F& f, Args... args)
    {
        std::cout << "intercept";
        (mobject.*f)(args...);
    }

private:
    T mObject;
};
```

Then I use it as so:

```
struct thing{
    void doSomething(char c) { cout << "dosomething on " << c; };
};

Wrapper<thing> p;
p.operation(&thing::doSomething, 'g');
```

Which is fine, and outputs "Intercept then dosomething on g". Then if I try to use the other constructor of Wrapper like so:

```
Wrapper<thing> p2(thing());
p2.operation(&thing::doSomething, 'f');
```

VS2013 gives a compile failure on the line where I try to call something on p2. It says that the left of operation is not a class/struct/union.

huh? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This declares a function `p2`:

```
Wrapper<thing> p2(thing());
```

which returns `Wrapper<thing>` and has a single unnamed parameter of type `thing(*)()`. You need:

```
Wrapper<thing> p2((thing()));
```

or

```
thing t;
Wrapper<thing> p2(t);
```

Comment: Nitpicker's corner: as declared, `p2` does not take a parameter of type `thing`, but of type `thing()` - a function taking no parameters and returning `thing`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Almost. To be really exact, it's a function *pointer* `thing(*)()`. Updated the answer.

Comment: If VS2013's C++11 syntax allows it, "`Wrapper<thing> p2(thing{});`" should also work. The braces force what's inside `p2`'s initializer to be an object, so it can't be a function declaration.